# Executing a command every second while taking into account the time it takes the command to run

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that reads the time in `%H:%M:%S` format, draws it on an image, and sets that image as the wallpaper. And it works just fine:

[image]

Now every five seconds or so, the script skips a second. I believe it's the time that takes the script to do the work that accumulates to a second every five seconds or so. But I don't know how to fix it.

Here's the loop that sets the time:

```sh
while sleep 1; do set_clock; done
```

And here's the `set_clock` function:

```sh
set_clock() {
        clock_time=$(date +'%H:%M:%S')
        convert \
                -size $monitor_resolution \
                xc:$background_color \
                -font $clock_font \
                -fill $clock_color \
                -pointsize $clock_size \
                -gravity Center \
                -draw "text 0,0 '$clock_time'" \
                "$config_dir/background.png"

        feh --bg-scale "$config_dir/background.png"
}
```

I don't think all of the script is necessary here, but [it can be found on my GitHub page](https://github.com/amirashabani/bwall/blob/master/bwall).

How can I fix this? So that the time shown is accurate.

Comment: A lazy fix would be to just run it twice a second, by doing `sleep 0.5` instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge A man after my own heart! We like easy fixes :-)

Comment: What is the point of this? Just use a clock widget.

Comment: Or just run `set_clock` in the background, so that it doesn't count towards the 1 second iteration time.

Comment: @oguzismail It's not just the clock, I'm planning to add more stuff to the wallpaper. And I'm not using any Desktop Environments, I'm using Window Managers (bspwm at the moment). I haven't found any such widgets that can be as customizable as writing my own script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a main ticking timer and run the `set_clock` in the background until end of current second like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set_clock() {
  printf -v clock_time '%(%H:%M:%S)T'

  convert \
    -size "$monitor_resolution" \
    "xc:$background_color" \
    -font "$clock_font" \
    -fill "$clock_color" \
    -pointsize "$clock_size" \
    -gravity 'Center' \
    -draw 'text' '0,0' "$clock_time" \
    "$config_dir/background.png"

  feh --bg-scale "$config_dir/background.png"
}

while :; do
  # Start the clock update in the background
  set_clock&

  # Sleep until the end of the current second
  sleep .$((10**9-10#$(date +%N)))

  # If there is a background child set_clock still running, kill it!
  { kill -0 $! && kill $!;} 2>/dev/null
done
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but `[ -n "$!" ]` will always be true, since the value of `$!` does not change when the child terminates.  Would be better to use a different method to test if the child has completed (to avoid sending a signal to an unintended recipient).

Comment: I really liked that subsecond sleep trick, but still can't see the point in using signals for this. `while sleep ...; do set_clock & done` does the same thing, no?

Comment: @oguzismail Yes, using a signal is overkill not needed here ^^

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable called `delay`.  After calling `set_clock`, use `date +%N` to get the current nanoseconds. Set `delay` to 1 minus the current nanoseconds, and change your loop to say `while sleep $delay` instead of `while sleep 1`.

That way, your loop will only sleep until the top of the next second.

This will only fix the problem if the construction and display of the image *always* take less than a second.  If the system is very busy and your process requires more than a second to complete, it'll still skip a second.

Answer (score 2):

You need something that keeps track of the starting time, and calculates the correct amount of time to sleep before you repeat.

It's possible to write it yourself, but it's easier to just use `watch` with the `-p`/`--precise` argument:

```
$ watch -n 1 -p 'sleep 0.5; date +%s.%N'
```

Even though the repeated command sleeps a half second, it won't delay the next one; you'll get about the same number of milliseconds each time.

Hm. It won't work with shell functions, though, since `watch` will execute your commands in a child process. You'd have to expand the whole command into the watch argument, which might be inconvenient with your relatively long command.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
while sleep $(perl -MTime::HiRes=gettimeofday -E '$n=gettimeofday; say 1-($n-int($n))'); do
...
done
```

Note that you may want to do the sleep *after* you've done the commands that take time.  Something like:

```
while slow_cmd; do
        perl -MTime::HiRes=gettimeofday,usleep -w -e '$n=gettimeofday; 
            usleep 1e6*(1-($n-int($n)))'
        update_status  # Quick cmd to report results of slow_cmd
done
```

You can try using `date` to get the high-resolution timer, but I find perl in practice to be more portable and less suprising.  Also, note that I've pushed the sleep into perl in the second form for the same reason.  (That is, sleep often does not accept sub-second precision, but `perl`'s usleep does.)